# Histogram Generation with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array with timestamps in `ts_array` following the format `dd-mm-yyyy` like `03-08-2012`. Now I want to plot a histogram using `matplotlib 1.5.1` and `Python 2.7` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timestamps = dict((x, ts_array.count(x)) for x in ts_array)

plt.hist(timestamps)
plt.title("Timestamp Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

Where e.g. `timestamps = {'03-08-2012': 108, '15-08-2012': 16}`.

When I try to run it it throws `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. How can I plot a histogram with the dates (keys) on the x-axis and the counts (values) on the y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think your having, although I'm uncertain as I don't know what `ts_array` looks like, is that `hist` attempts to create a histogram and then plot that in a bar chart. What you want is just to plot a bar chart: from your statement it looks like `timestamps` is the data needed to generate that bar chart?

So you could for example do this:

```
timestamps = {'03-08-2012': 108, '15-08-2012': 16}  # Sample data

# Get the heights and labels from the dictionary
heights, labels = [], []
for key, val in timestamps.iteritems():
    labels.append(key)
    heights.append(val)

# Create a set of fake indexes at which to place the bars
indexes = np.arange(len(timestamps))
width = 0.4

# Generate a matplotlib figure and plot the bar chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(indexes, heights)

# Overwrite the axis labels
ax.set_xticks(indexes + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

This is a somewhat modified version of the [example in the docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html). Hopefully that helps.